# Assimilated Bucharian Jews

Tags: halacha, gentiles, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

I was told that there is a discussion regarding the Jewishness of Bucharian Jews, because they were forced into being assimilated into the surrounding gentile culture, (perhaps the discussion was by Rav Amar). Does anyone know where their status is discussed in Halachic literature?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F_PW9P6dqlR0NHLWpfZUdUSzA/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8F_PW9P6dqlUk9pSDlubUl3ckk

Comment: Aren't Bukarian Jews more Ashkenazi in customs than Sephardi? Or am I just wrong?

Comment: @EzraHoerster yes due to the influence of Chabad shluchim traveling to buchara

Comment: @shmuel Perhaps you would be interested in [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73525/8775) which discusses some of the history of the Ashkenazi and Sephardi cultures.